# How can I check if a URL is absolute using Python?

Tags: python

What is the preferred solution for checking if an URL is relative or absolute?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

## Python 2

You can use the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module to parse an URL and then you can check if it's relative or absolute by checking whether it has the host name set.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> def is_absolute(url):
...     return bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc)
... 
>>> is_absolute('http://www.example.com/some/path')
True
>>> is_absolute('//www.example.com/some/path')
True
>>> is_absolute('/some/path')
False
```

## Python 3

`urlparse` has been moved to `urllib.parse`, so use the following:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def is_absolute(url):
    return bool(urlparse(url).netloc)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `www.example.com/some/path` count as abolute too?

Comment: Officially, that's an relative URL with the whole string as path. If you want it to count as absolute, you would have to either add the `http://` by some pre-processing or not use `urlparse`.

Comment: According to RFC `//google.com` is a protocol-relative url. And your code will return `False` for it.

Comment: I'd prefer `urlsplit` instead of `urlparse`. BTW, in Django you have a Python 2 & 3 compatible way: `from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlparse`

Comment: If you want Python 2 & 3 compatibility just use six module (`six.moves.urllib.parse`) -> https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves.urllib.parse

Comment: @Nik not for me: In [27]: urlparse('//google.com')
Out[27]: ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='google.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')

Answer (score 31):

If you want to know if an URL is absolute or relative in order to join it with a base URL, I usually do `urllib.parse.urljoin` anyway:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('http://example.com/', 'http://example.com/picture.png')
'http://example.com/picture.png'
>>> urljoin('http://example1.com/', '/picture.png')
'http://example1.com/picture.png'
>>>
```

Comment: It turns out that this is what I wanted to do - it treats the first URL as the default for all unspecified parts of the second URL.  If the second one is absolute, it just uses that one.

Comment: Anyone using this should be aware that if given `http://www.yahoo.com` and `www.google.com` as inputs, this will give you `http://www.yahoo.com/www.google.com` as output, which probably isn't what you wanted. So you'll still have to check somehow if the second one is a url without a schema,  or if actually a relative path.

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment accepted answer, so write this comment as new answer: IMO checking scheme in accepted answer ( `bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).scheme)` ) is not really good idea because of http://example.com/file.jpg, https://example.com/file.jpg and //example.com/file.jpg are absolute urls but in last case we get scheme = ''

I use this code:

`is_absolute = True if '//' in my_url else False`

Comment: AFAIK //foo/bar is a valid relative URL. With "relative" meaning "without scheme and netloc".

Answer (score -2):

```bash
pip install yarl
```

```py
import yarl

if not yarl.URL(image).is_absolute():
    image = context["request"].build_absolute_uri(image)
```

because

```py
yarl.URL("//google.com").is_absolute() is True
True
```

in the opposite to

```
urllib.parse.urlsplit("//google.com").scheme == ""
True
```

`netloc` is still defined though

```
urllib.parse.urlsplit("//google.com").netloc == "google.com"
```

Pros.

- easier to read
- easier to test (you can mock one particular method)

Cons.

- extra deps (but pretty stable one)

Comment: What is `yarl`? Please read [answer].

Comment: Python library. Well known

Comment: Don't assume that anything is "well known". The edited answer is better, but still not great: commands and code without any context rarely make a good answer. In this case you're asking folks to install some random package. What makes this better than the solution that uses the built-in `urllib.parse.urljoin` recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357262/354577)? Again, please read [answer].

Comment: Using yarl is better because you move away from knowing the internal structure of the url. Easier to use and easier to test