# How to get the link inside the li tag?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://download.cnet.com/windows/"
pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)
for a in soup.select("div.catFlyout a[href]"):
    print "http://download.cnet.com"+a["href"]
```

But this code did not give the correct output.
The correct output should be like this:

```
http://download.cnet.com/windows/security-software/
http://download.cnet.com/windows/browsers/
http://download.cnet.com/windows/business-software/
..
..
http://download.cnet.com/windows/video-software/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some relative and absolute links in the list, prepend base url only if the link starts with `http`:

```
for a in soup.select("div.catFlyout a[href]"):
    if not a["href"].startswith("http"):
        print "http://download.cnet.com"+a["href"]
    else:
        print a["href"]
```

Or, use `urlparse` to check if link is absolute or not (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357518/771848)):

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def is_absolute(url):
    return bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).scheme)

url = "http://download.cnet.com/windows/"
pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)
for a in soup.select("div.catFlyout a[href]"):
    if not is_absolute(a['href']):
        print "http://download.cnet.com"+a["href"]
    else:
        print a["href"]
```

Comment: How if want to take only the category link,not all sub inside the category? @alexce

Comment: @wanmohdpayed what do you mean by category links? Links that doesn't end with `html`?

Comment: I mean I want only the link under the category. I dont want the sub link inside the link under the category. @alexce