# Get relative links from html page

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I want to extract only relative urls from html page; somebody has suggest this :

```
find_re = re.compile(r'\bhref\s*=\s*("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^"\'<>=\s]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

but it return  :

1/all absolute and relative urls from the page.

2/the url may be quated by `""` or `''` randomly .

Comment: Could you try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags): an `HTML parser`, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

You can [pass a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) as an attribute value to [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and check whether `href` starts with `http`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
<a href="http://google.com">test1</a>
<a href="test2">test2</a>
<a href="http://amazon.com">test3</a>
<a href="here/we/go">test4</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.find_all('a', href=lambda x: not x.startswith('http'))
```

Or, using [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) and [checking for network location part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357518/771848):

```
def is_relative(url):
    return not bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc)

print soup.find_all('a', href=is_relative)
```

Both solutions print:

```
[<a href="test2">test2</a>, 
 <a href="here/we/go">test4</a>]
```