# urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed?

Tags: python-3.x

Hello everyone I am a beginner programmer in language `Python` and I need help.

this is my code in Python, it gives an error, please help to fix

> urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

**Python:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
from lxml.html import parse

WEBSITE = 'http://allrecipes.com'

URL_PAGE = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/110/appetizers-and-snacks/deviled-eggs/?page='

START_PAGE = 1
END_PAGE = 5

def correct_str(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()

for i in range(START_PAGE, END_PAGE+1):
    URL = URL_PAGE + str(i)
    HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    page = parse(HTML).getroot()

    for elem in page.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/article[not(contains(@class, "video-card"))]/a[1]'):
        href = WEBSITE + elem.get('href')
        title = correct_str(elem.find('h3').text)

        recipe_page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(href)).getroot()
        print(correct_str(href))
        photo_url = recipe_page.xpath('//img[@class="rec-photo"]')[0].get('src')

        print('\nName:  |', title)
        print('Photo: |', photo_url)
```

**This into command prompt: python I get this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
http://allrecipes.com/recipe/236225/crab-stuffed-deviled-eggs/
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1240, in do_open

    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
Name:  | Crab-Stuffed Deviled Eggs
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
Photo: | http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/720x405/1091564.jpg
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 826, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ivan/Dropbox/parser/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    recipe_page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(href)).getroot()
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1242, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll attempt to explain three main ways to dig into a programming problem:

(1) Use a debugger.  You could walk through your code and examine variables before they are used and before they throw an exception.  Python comes with `pdb`.  In this problem you would step through the code and print out the `href` before `urlopen()`.

(2) Assertions.  Use Python's `assert` to assert assumptions in your code.  You could, for example, `assert not href.startswith('http')`

(3) Logging.  Log relevant variables before they are used.  This is what I used:

I added the following to your code...

```
href = WEBSITE + elem.get('href')                                       
print(href)
```

And got...

```
Photo: | http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/720x405/1091564.jpg
http://allrecipes.comhttp://dish.allrecipes.com/how-to-boil-an-egg/
```

From here you can see your `getaddrinfo` problem:  Your system is trying to open a url at a host named `allrecipes.comhttp`.

This looks to be a problem based upon your assumption that `WEBSITE` must be prepended to every `href` you pull from the html.

You can handle the case of an absolute vs relative `href` with something like this and [a function to determine if the url is absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357098/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-is-absolute-using-python):

```
import urlparse
def is_absolute(url):
    # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357098/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-is-absolute-using-python
    return bool(urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc)

href = elem.get('href')                                                 
if not is_absolute(href):
    href = WEBSITE + href
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to use parse as such:

```
    from urllib import parse
    href = parse.urljoin(base_url, href)
```

This will will return a complete url for the href in case it is not complete.