# How to download files from a webpage using python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am trying to create a script that scrapes a webpage and downloads any image files found.

My first function is a wget function that reads the webpage and assigns it to a variable.
My second function is a RegEx that searches for the 'ssrc=' in a webpages html, below is the function:

```
def find_image(text):
    '''Find .gif, .jpg and .bmp files'''
    documents = re.findall(r'\ssrc="([^"]+)"', text) 
    count = len(documents)
    print "[+] Total number of file's found: %s" % count
    return '\n'.join([str(x) for x in documents])
```

The output from this is something like this:

```
example.jpg
image.gif
http://www.webpage.com/example/file01.bmp
```

I am trying to write a third function that downloads these files using urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename) but I am not sure how to go about this, mainly because some of the output is absolute paths where as others are relative. I am also unsure how to download these all at same time and download without me having to specify a name and location every time.

Comment: don't parse html with regexes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Path-Agnostic fetching of resources (Can handle absolute/relative paths) -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urlparse
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlretrieve
import os

def fetch_url(url, out_folder="test/"):
    """Downloads all the images at 'url' to /test/"""
    soup = bs(urlopen(url))
    parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(url))

    for image in soup.findAll("img"):
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        filename = image["src"].split("/")[-1]
        parsed[2] = image["src"]
        outpath = os.path.join(out_folder, filename)
        if image["src"].lower().startswith("http"):
            urlretrieve(image["src"], outpath)
        else:
            urlretrieve(urlparse.urlunparse(parsed), outpath)

fetch_url('http://www.w3schools.com/html/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't write you the complete code and I'm sure that's not what you would want as well, but here are some hints:

1) Do **not** parse random HTML pages with regex, there are quite a few parsers made for that. I suggest [BeautifulSoup](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python). You will filter all `img` elements and get their `src` values.

2) With the `src` values at hand, you download your files the way you are already doing. About the relative/absolute problem, use the `urlparse` module, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357098/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-is-absolute-using-python). The idea is to join the `src` of the image with the URL from which you downloaded the HTML. If the `src` is already absolute, it will remain that way.

3) As for downloading them all, simply iterate over a list of the webpages you want to download images from and do steps 1 and 2 for each image in each page. When you say "at the same time", you probably mean to download them asynchronously. In that case, I suggest downloading each webpage [in one thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).